# Exporting a csv file with multiline to a single cell

Tags: android, export-to-csv

In my android application, I need to export data as CSV format with multiline in a single cell, based on that I have used the below code to export CSV. After successfully exported to select and view that file by using any one of the CSV viewer like [CSV Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.shira.csv.viewer&hl=en),[CSV Modify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.shira.csv.modify&hl=en) which is opening and showing these lines "this\nis\nsome\ntext" in different row instead of a single cell but I open in excel sheet which is working as expected. But my requirement is should also work on CSV viewer applications.
Any suggestions?

[image]

**I want to like the below**
[image]

```
        String multilineString="this\nis\nsome\ntext";
        File storageDir = RLogApp.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        File serviceCallDataFile = new File(storageDir, "/" + "servicelist.csv");
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        data.add(new String[]{"India", "New Delhi"});
        data.add(new String[]{"United States",
                "\""+multilineString+"\""
        });
        data.add(new String[]{"Germany", "Berlin"});
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(serviceCallDataFile));
            writer.writeAll(data);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Your post is unclear. So you create a cv file and excel displays it as you want and those csv apps not? Unclear.

Comment: If so... Then what is the question?

Comment: @greenapps yes excel displays what i want but csv apps not working as expected.

Comment: Then what is the question? I would conclude that those apps do not support multiline items. And you?

Comment: Probably because you are using **CSVWriter**, which automatically transforms the data to be CSV-compliant and this is **not** what you want. I'd use a FileOutputStream, instead. After all, CSV files are plain text files. Don't be lazy...

Comment: @NoiseGenerator, Then what would be different in the resulting file? Remember that excel does not complain.

Comment: @greenapps You can manage how to output the file **exactly**. Which means using the **`;`** field terminators Excel expects (oh, yes! Excel wants semicolons!), for instance.

Comment: It works already in excel. So what should be changed then? Come to the point!

Comment: @greenapps Then the problem is in the Viewers the OP is using.

Comment: `CSV Modify`. Use that app  to type a multi line in an item. Do you succeed? How does the resulting file look like?

Comment: @greenapps I used CSV Viewer+Editor application and able to type multiple lines.

Comment: `How does the resulting file look like?` Why no answer ??? But can you save them too? And reload from file? Then show us the resulting file. Use wordpad or notepad to copy/paste some lines to here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String multilineString="this\nis\nsome\ntext";
```

Replace by

```
 String multilineString="this\\nis\\nsome\\ntext";
```

And

```
"\""+multilineString+"\""
```

Replace by

```
multilineString
```

Well you could try..

Comment: Inspect a working file with a plain text editor like wordpad or notepad. How does it look then?

Comment: Does excel still display then ok?

Comment: My requirement is should work on CSVviewer applications, not excel.